# drawElementsInstanced with OpenGL and Java

Tags: java, opengl, geometry-instancing

I'm trying to render one triangle  100 times on different locations with `glDrawElementsInstanced()`.

I'm not getting it the right way. I tried different tutorials, but their all for c++ and not for java. The last one is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMVhGJkALW0).

Here is my example code:

```
float offsets = new float[300];

int i = 0;
float offset = 0.1f;
for (int x = -10; x < 10; x += 2) {
    for (int y = -10; y < 10; y += 2) {
        offsets[i] = (float) x / 10.0f + offset;
        offsets[i + 1] = (float) y / 10.0f + offset;
        offsets[i + 2] = 0.0f;
        i += 3;
    }
}        

FloatBuffer attribData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer( offsets.length );
attribData.put( offsets, 0,offsets.length );
attribData.flip();


int bufferID = glGenBuffer();       
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,          m_iUsage );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attribData, m_iUsage );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index);
glVertexAttribPointer(index,3,GL_FLOAT, false,0,null);
glVertexAttribDivisor(index,1);

glBindVertexArray( m_iVAOid );
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0, 100);
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

this is my vertexShader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec3 aColor;
layout(location=2) in vec3 aOffset;

out vec3 fColor;

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView;
uniform mat4 uProjection;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = uProjection * uView * uModel* vec4(aPosition+aOffset, 1.0);
    fColor = aColor;
}
```

at the moment i render one square with the center in 0,0,0.

Comment: and what does your vertex shader looks like? What is rendered so far?

Comment: I see nothing wrong in supplied code. Double check if your uniforms are set

Comment: is your vao binded when you call glVertexAttribFunctions? if not it's a fault